# How to join 2 or more tables with same column name every table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Imagine that i have 2 tables
First, table1 with column

```
name
score1
score2
```

And second table is

```
name
score1
score2
```

Expected output:

```
name
t1.score1
t1.score2
t2.score1
t2.score2
```

Can i make it with 1 query if the name column have same value in both tables.
And how do i echo it in php?

Thanks for any insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your SQL query. Using the following will produce a result with the columns you provided.

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.score1 as t1score1, t1.score2 as t1score2, t2.score1 as t2score1, t2.score2 as t2score2
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```

> And how do i echo it in php?

For easy access, you have to rename the columns to have distinct names. These can be accessed in php.

Comment: Good catch on the distinct column names, yours is better than mine. I'm up-voting you. -jwolf

Comment: Wow thanks for the help, i'm on school right now, i'll try your solution after school. Hope it solve my problems

Comment: Wow, you have saved my life, thanks a lot for your answer, icould able to display several column with same names on different tables, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are listing all of your columns vertically so I'm going to take your expected output as a simple column listing:

```
select a.name, a.score1, a.score2, b.score1, b.bscore2
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on b.name = a.name
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i really appreciate everything, Hope it'll solve my problem